# Ubuntu language in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, language-support

I've made an upgrade from Kubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 it worked ok. But later I got a message that said something like "Language support is not complete do you want to install now?"  If I accept, the process begins, but almost immediately a message appears, saying "Updates impossible".  The options are "Ok" and "More info".  Ok ends the process and "More info" does not do anything.

What can I do?  The messages may not be exactly the same because my installation is in Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it happens, but to make it 'shut up' you can install missing language support by opening a terminal window and running this command:

```
sudo apt install $(check-language-support)
```